# Why tag <img> placed to <router-link> gets by default CSS property "display:none !important"? How to avoid this?

Tags: html, css, vue-router

Why tag "IMG" placed to "router-link" tag, automatically gets by default  "display:none !important" CSS property? I didn't use CSS style that could hide it. Is it correct to place "IMG" tag inside "A" tag? **How to avoid this situation?**

```
<router-link to="#">
 <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c625327/v625327331/33d5f/7rLtQQMckIA.jpg"     alt="test">
</router-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer. The problem was with my AddBlock app installed in my browser. My folder, where I store the image, had name "ad", and also the name of image file was containing the same word - "ad". When I changed the name of the folder and the name of the image file, the problem was solved.

Tag "router-link" was working correct all this time.